# Users want to have a maximum of three relevant keywords to tag the articles

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

We are currently working on a project to automate the process for our articles preparation team.
We are using Azure Cognitive Service’s Text Analytics to extract key phrases from the articles. However, it extracted nearly 10 keywords.

Is that any weight can be provided to show the importance/quality/relevant of the key phase? or any other better approach to pick top N key phase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key phrase extraction tool returns the phrases in order of importance. If you select the top 3, you should get the three most important phrases for the document.
What is text summarization in [Azure Cognitive Service for Language (preview)? - Azure Cognitive Services | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/text-summarization/overview)